# Store markup in resource dictionaries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I want to reduce the contents of `MainWindow.xaml` file and put parts of it in resources (because they are used only once in the design and take up a lot of space in `MainWindow.xaml` markup). Namely, I want to make `Grid` markups with content.

I'm trying to learn this using a simple example. Firstly, I create resource files `Grid1.xaml` and `Grid2.xaml` that contain that contains a lot of content inside:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://...">
    <Grid x:Key="ResourceGrid1">
        ... <!-- a lot of content -->
    </Grid>
</ResourceDictionary>

<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://...">
    <Grid x:Key="ResourceGrid2">
        ... <!-- a lot of content -->
    </Grid>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then, I add the files to the resource dictionary `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Grid1.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Grid2.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And finally, I want to embed the contents of the resources in `MainWindow.xaml` file:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceGrid1}" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceGrid2}" />
</Grid>
```

I do not get errors, nor do I get the expected result (displaying the contents of `Grid1.xaml` and `Grid2.xaml` files in the main grid `MainGrid`). What am I doing wrong? How can I insert the contents of files into the main markup? Thank

Comment: DataContext is not meant to create UI. Use the resource as Content of a ContentControl or ContentPresenter. Or move the Grids into DataTemplates. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Thank. It works.